# feeding a list of objects to rbind.fill

Tags: r, list, rbind

I have a large number or tables in the environment I wish to bind into a single table.  There are many tables in the environment, but all the ones I want to bind are similarly named ending in "_Fields".  I wish to search the environment for all the so-named tables and bind them together.

Using the grep function I can search and find all the table names as follows:

`mylist <- list(grep("_Fields", ls(), value=T))`

This yields the following result for *mylist*:

```
 [[1]]
 [1] "Account_Fields"            "AccountHistory_Fields"     "Case_Fields"               "CaseHistory_Fields"        "Contact_Fields"           
 [6] "Lead_Fields"               "LeadHistory_Fields"        "Opportunity_Fields"        "OpportunityHistory_Fields" "User_Fields"
```

These are names of the desired tables in the environment, and I wish to bind them with the following:

`tmp <- do.call(plyr::rbind.fill,mylist)`

However all this yields is the list of names contained in mylist and not the bound tables.  How do I get the list of objects to be passed to the function to bind the tables?

The following works, but the number of tables may vary and I would have to change this code each time.

````
mylist <- list(Account_Fields,Opportunity_Fields,Lead_Fields,Contact_Fields,
            User_Fields,Case_Fields,AccountHistory_Fields,OpportunityHistory_Fields,
            LeadHistory_Fields, CaseHistory_Fields)

tmp <- do.call(plyr::rbind.fill,mylist)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `mget`

```
do.call(rbind.fill, mget(ls(pattern = "_Fields")))
```

Comment: ugh ... so simple and it works !  Thank you.